# How does one Serialize a JBoss Drools KieBase collection for external storage?

Tags: java, concurrency, redis, drools

This might actually have nothing to do with Drools itself, but maybe just have a Java native solution. I'm just a total Java noob and inheriting a project so I'm trying to understand best practises.

We have a rules based multi-tenant system where business rules can be configured dynamically by our clients. We store the compiled rules for each client in a `ConcurrentHashMap` that looks like this

`ConcurrentMap<String, KieBase> rules = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

Where the `string` is a UUID representing each unique client. The problem with this however is that horizontally scaling out the calculations is a problem since this is just an in memory hashmap that gets recompiled on every change. If we scaled it out, every client would need to listen to the new rule changes and recompile every time that happens, which feels like a waste since they'll always yield the same results.

**My end goal is to store these calculated rules outside of the JVM so that multiple instances can share the compiled rules and any one of those instances could safely, concurrently recompile the rules for a particular client while all other instances that may need rules for *that client* would wait**

So my thought was to use Redis as a k/v lock/store where the key would be the client_id and the value would be a serialized version of the Drools KieBase object. Recalculations would lock the redis store on that key using a [transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) (or some comparable locking algorithm) so that other instances needing the KieBase for that client_id would wait until compilation is complete and written back to the db.

So I have a few questions:

1. Is the serialization of this KieBase object a Drools specific thing or is there a generic Marshalling serialization mechanism in Java for any object (and is this recommended?)
2. Would something like [reddisson](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) do exactly what I'm looking for? If so, does anyone have a snippet that would point me in the right direction? I basically need a lock on a key for each client so that multiple instances would block while one is being calculated, but I preferably don't want to lock the whole db, just that one entry in the hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

A simple ObjectOutputStream is sufficient for serializing a KieBase object. Below it is used for writing to a file, but you can create a String or byte[] by writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream and taking the result in either form.

```
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( OUTPATH );
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( fos );
oos.writeObject( kieBase );
oos.close();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( OUTPATH );
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( fis );
KieBase kieBase1 = (KieBase)ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

As for locking, that depends on whether you need to lock an external representation against multiple applications running parallel (in a network), or whether there is a single (server) application that keeps everything in the HashMap. In the latter case, any Java Object has a monitor:

```
synchronized( idString ) {
    idString.wait();    // or overloaded form with timeout
}

// different thread 
synchronized( idString ){
    idString.notify();
}
```

You might consult Brian Goetz' book "Java Concurrency in Practice".

**Edit**
Any decent DB has a write locking mechanism. Also, in your case you might even be able to manage with a simple file storage and file locking, available on MS Windows and all Unices.

Comment: Thanks. I just clarified my end goal above, which is to do the _former_ in your "depends" scenario, which is sharing this hashmap amongst multiple running java processes. I'll look into the ByteArray stuff though that gives me a good start. It seems like I could store that ByteArray directly in Redis using Jedis. As for locking, I'm not sure if I can just get away with Redis transactions, or if I need a more advanced algorithm like something that Redisson does

Comment: Any decent DB has a write locking mechanism. Also, in your case you might even be able to manage with a simple file storage and file locking, available on MS Windows and all Unices.

Comment: I need a public interface to the db, so I can horizontally scale. I think ultimately I've found that Redisson will probably do what I want. It will deal with the distributed concurrency issue and allow me to serialize the objects into redis